# Error in Level Order Traversal of Binary Tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

***What mistake have i done here ?***

```
def levelOrder(root):
#Write your code here
que = []
que.append(root)
while que != []:
    coot = que.pop()
    print(coot.data,end=" ")

    if coot.left is not None:
        que.append(coot.left)

    if coot.right is not None:
        que.append(coot.right)
```

OutPut Expected:`1 2 5 3 6 4`

MY_output: 1 2 5 **6 3** 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending nodes to end end of the list `que`(using `append()`). And also *removing the nodes from the end of the list* `que`(using `list.pop()`), this would not preserve the order, so for something like

```
             1
            /  \
           2    3 
          / \   / \
         4   5  6  7
```

After first iteration would have `que=[2, 3]`, and then you would pop 3 first instead of 2, which is incorrect. Instead, you should be popping 2, popping from the left(since you are appending the new nodes to the right).

So replacing `coot = que.pop()` with `coot = que.pop(0)` in your existing code should fix the issue. But note that `list.pop(0)` is a **O(n)** operation python. So I would suggest using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead.

With deque, your code can be -

```
from collections import deque
def levelOrder(root):
    #Write your code here
    que = deque()
    que.append(root)
    while que != []:
        coot = que.popleft()
        print(coot.data,end=" ")

        if coot.left is not None:
            que.append(coot.left)

        if coot.right is not None:
            que.append(coot.right)
```